# Cypress Remove Grid from index

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using in Cypress this code.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("getProductDetails", (path, productName, productDescription) => {
cy.get(path).each(($el, index) => {
    if ($el.text().includes(productName)) {           
        cy.get('div[class]> p[data-testid="product-desc"]').eq(index).should('contain.text', productDescription)
        cy.get('div[role="product-overview"] *> a[data-testid="product-details-link"]').eq(index).click()
    }
})
```

})

I have problem, if the 'productName' is the same at the beginning. For example I have Products CONNECTED PACKAGE and CONNECTED PACKAGE EXCELLENCE.  In the index I have 2 elements. Please, which is the best practice in Cypress to fix this issue?

Thank you

Michal

Comment: What abount `$el.text() === productName` for an exact match?

Comment: Hi Steve, it unfortunately doesn't work. The problem is, that by I includes all the product names elements. I have the [{ProductName1, ProductName2 etc..}]. By using an exact match, it will don't work. Have tried by changing the path, but was not successful. I will think about it and maybe I find solution with your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Steve, I changed the path Locator and your suggestion works. Thank you for your help :)